# Bootstrap menu focus background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a simple drilldown in Bootstrap.  When the user selects a "row", I want the background color to change to indicate what "row" is selected. It only works like I want it on the first level rows.

Here's the basic HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-drilldown" id="Menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-target="#a" data-parent="Menu" data-toggle="collapse">Thing the first</a>
      <ul class="collapse" id="a">
      <li><a href="#" data-target="#a-child-1" data-parent="a" data-toggle="collapse">child 1</a></li>
          <ul class="collapse" id="a-child-1">
            <li>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">something</div>
                <div class="col-md-3">goes</div>
                <div class="col-md-3">here</div>                
              </div>

            </li>
          </ul>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.nav-drilldown:focus {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.nav-drilldown li li a:focus {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

.nav-drilldown li a:focus {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

For the second level, on the text part of the anchor changes background color.  I get that you can't set selected on a `<li>`, but i don't understand why the second level doesn't behave like the first level. I can't get the third level to much of anything.

Level 1:
[image]

Level 2:
[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnyaya/7xsz1w8s/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is just a matter of the padding on the anchor tag.  At the top level, you have 10px top and bottom padding and on the second level anchor tag, you have no padding.  So, if you want similar behavior, you could add:

```
.nav-drilldown li li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

Comment: That only changes the height, I'm trying to get them all to be the same width.

Comment: ah - the first level focus I believe was the first/outer li element was a display:block.  So, you can add `display:block` to the `.nav-drilldown li li a` css definition and that should fix it.

Comment: That's perfect for the second level, any ideas for the third level (which doesn't have an anchor tag)?

Comment: Well, the `:focus` selector only works on elements with user input (inputs or anchor tags and the like).  So, you need to either add a click handler for the third level and use javascript to change the background, or you have to add a similar type html user-interaction element like an anchor tag (or tags) to the third level.  Does that make sense?